# make some text (link) invisible in small display (mobile)

Tags: html, css

i want to make this text visible in normal display, but invisible in small display.

```html
<div class="topnav">
      <div id="top-links" class="nav-float-right">
       <ul class="list-inline">
        
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ account }}" title="{{ text_account }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span><font size="2">{{ text_account }}</font></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            {% if logged %}
            <li><a href="{{ account }}">{{ text_account }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ order }}">{{ text_order }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ transaction }}">{{ text_transaction }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ download }}">{{ text_download }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ logout }}">{{ text_logout }}</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ register }}">{{ text_register }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ login }}">{{ text_login }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
      </div>
```

i search in google for solution and tried many things. but unsuccessful. please let me know how to fix this issue.
thanks

Comment: CSS media queries.

Comment: How is PHP related to this?

Comment: Which text you want to hide? the whole navbar?

Comment: _"and tried many things"_ - such as? I mean, there are _many many_ guides about this online.

Comment: the whole navbar, yes. @NanditaAroraSharma

Comment: `@media (max-width: 278px) { #nav-float-right a { width: 100%; float: center; display: none; visibility: hidden; } }`  @u_mulder

Comment: its not? my bad, sorry. @Mehdi

Comment: which text you want to be invisible?? and what have you written in % ages??can you explain

Comment: Are you using bootstrap framework for your coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a look at this for it change your code atonce this is for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>click demo</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>




 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- jQuery library -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Text 1</li>
        <li>Text 2</li>
        <li>Text 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Text 4</li>
        <li>Text 5</li>
        <li>Text 6</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Text 7</li>
        <li>Text 8</li>
        <li>Text 9</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="hidden-xs col-sm-3">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Text 10</li>
        <li>Text 11</li>
        <li>Text 12</li>
        </ul>
    </nav></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

have a look at the fiddle it works with navbar jsu resize to see effect:https://jsfiddle.net/2aeupsq8/

for your code do this :

```
  <div class="container">
      <nav class="hidden-xs">
      <div class="topnav">
        <div id="top-links" class="nav-float-right">
         <ul class="list-inline">

          <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ account }}" title="{{ text_account }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span><font size="2">{{ text_account }}</font></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              {% if logged %}
              <li><a href="{{ account }}">{{ text_account }}</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ order }}">{{ text_order }}</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ transaction }}">{{ text_transaction }}</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ download }}">{{ text_download }}</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ logout }}">{{ text_logout }}</a></li>
              {% else %}
              <li><a href="{{ register }}">{{ text_register }}</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{ login }}">{{ text_login }}</a></li>
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
        </div>  
      </nav>
    </div>
```

reszie the screeen to see the effect:
https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/ferowusa/

Comment: @wasikovee you can also edit the nav as div but make sure you have class ="hidden-xs"in it

Comment: @wasikovee Thank you wasikovee you can also upvote it

Answer (score 1):

write media query  on your css 
@media (max-width: 780px) {
 .classname{
    display:none
}
 }
or use
Add Bootstrap class(class="hidden-xs")...its hide content on mobile screens..

Answer (score 0):

Try using media query like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav {
    display: none !important; 
  }
}
```

You can change `600px` value to whatever width you want to start hiding your navbar from

Comment: yep, i tried that. it works with 3 simple navbar. but not working with my navbar.

Comment: So is your issue solved? Or you face some other problem too with this ?

Comment: issue remains. still can not make it invisible in small display.

Comment: Try !important with the css

Comment: @wasikovee bootstarp will do it have a look above